# Bulk Update data in Cosmos SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I read the document and found that for doing bulk operation we can set AllowBulkExecution as true , but what is the difference between using AllowBulkExecution  and by running ReplaceItem methods in multiple thread using tasks.add(replaceItem)

Comment: Read: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/. And https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/1611

Comment: I have used both the approach but it seems there is no performance improvement .So wanted to know if I am missing something.

Comment: Does the RU cost of a single operation, and the configured RU/s, match with update throughput?

Comment: yes its same in either of the approach.

Comment: The question is: does your RU/s limit adequately explain your throughput?